# Npm Error while i try to execute npm run dev command in my terminal

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

I am a fresher and started my career just 4 months back.

I am using Ubuntu and laravel for the development of my project.I am trying to compile a .js file for which i installed npm and bower in my project folder. Installation was smooth and is complete.

But while executing the "npm run dev" i am getting the below error.

I executed the below command :

sudo n latest
 And the error is :

```
npm run dev

> npm run development


> @ development /
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:279:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:696:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vidya/.npm/_logs/2018-09-18T09_27_31_491Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vidya/.npm/_logs/2018-09-18T09_27_31_546Z-debug.log
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated .

```
NPM version:6.4.1
bower version: 1.8.4
ubuntu version:UBUNTU 16.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 1):

**Steps To Reproduce:**

Clean Laravel Installation (
composer create-project laravel/laravel webinterface)

```
run: composer install
run: npm install
run: npm run dev
```

Follow these steps:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072).

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code in my root and the issue got fixed.

```
sudo npm install -g PACKAGE-NAME --unsafe-perm=false --allow-root
```

I used below to install all the packages.

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm=false --allow-root
```

Npm is working fine now.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Should downgrade webpack-dev-server to:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@2.9.7
```